# What are the excitations in the near critical 2D-Ising model in a magnetic field?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, conformal-field-theory, ising-model, critical-phenomena

Apparently it is well known that the 2D Ising model with $T=T_C$ in a small magnetic field has a mass gap and correlation length $\xi \sim h^{- \frac{8}{15}} $. Further, in a paper in 1989 Zamolodchikov used CFT to predict/show that the Ising model in a magnetic field has 8 masses (and computed their mass ratios which is the golden ratio for the two heaviest ones) With masses meaning that the Fourier transform of the correlation function poles.

But which excitations does the 2D-Ising model have? Is there some physical interpretation of what the particles that these masses correspond to?